# Heroku not loading procfile

Tags: python, django, heroku

I've tried other peoples solutions to getting there procfile recognised and it's just not working for me. Really confused about how I can get heroku to recognize my Procfile! I've moved it around into different folders and whatnot but it just won't recognise it.

```
web: waitress-serve --port=$PORT alex1.wsgi:application
```

This is my code. It's sitting right next to my requirements.txt file which is getting picked up by heroku fine. using echo to create the file or even echo is not working.

https://github.com/Hewlbern/Videography-Website/tree/master/Alex1 <--- the github link that I'm trying to deploy to heroku from. Can see where i've placed it and etc if anyone can help!

Such sad, many mad.

EDIT
Put them at top of directory - still not working.

Here's the error log.

```
-----> Python app detected
 !     Warning: Your application is missing a Procfile. This file tells Heroku how to run your application.
 !     Learn more: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/procfile
-----> Installing requirements with pip
-----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
       63 static files copied to '/tmp/build_b9ce82b65ae441b651c56911a7474859/Hewlbern-ConsultingPage-1720e65/djreact/static/root'.
-----> Discovering process types
       Procfile declares types -> (none)
-----> Compressing...
       Done: 64.3M
-----> Launching...
       Released v19
       https://consultingpage.herokuapp.com/ deployed to Heroku
```

In response to Mike's point below I went through his example I reached this point.

```
C:\Users\Holbinator\Desktop\Software Dev\Alexandria>git push heroku master fatal: 'heroku' does not appear to be a git repository fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

I then re-did Git Init in the root directory and then tried to load the code from Github.
**This led to the same issue.** 
I'll put this in my edit. Thanks! I'm going to try and do your method now and work out why I couldn't in this instance.

**EDIT TWO**

Now realised I needed to delete a extra heroku app. Now loading the files using heroku cli. Have no received an error, unsure how to access error logs but will try and solve the issue now.

Comment: Both the Procfile and requirements.txt should be at the top level.

Comment: When putting it at the top level it still doesn't recognize it.

Comment: This is a wild guess but what's the permissions on Procfile?

Comment: I'm unsure! I'll have a look, it is in windows 10 so might be to do with this haha

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First point of my recommendation will be to put `.idea` directory in `.gitignore` file.

I've uploaded your application on heroku and as result -`Procfile` was added successfully.

**Steps:**

1. `git add .` in your root directory
2. `git commit -m "init commit"`
3. `heroku create`
4. `git push heroku master`

That's mine result, but you will probably see something similar to this : 
[image]
[image]

Afterwards I've launched your application via `heroku open` command and received the `500` error.

Screenshot of logs
[image]

I hope this answer will be useful, also read about [deploy on heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/getting-started-with-python#introduction)

**UPD:** Please check if you using `git init` in your root directory of project

Comment: Thanks Mike! Will check over this in the morning, quite late in Australia, but sounds like a good start for me to understand whats going on!

Comment: Welcome;) and please, write about your result;)

Comment: Fixed why I couldn't make the app, now will see result, soon to update!

Comment: I am stuck at the error message you received Mike - But it would appear that my procfile is now loading in this method. I still wonder by it won't load via github but you have definitely found a solution! 

Now to understand why it's not loading my module! Cheers!

Comment: Nice,   and I believe that you will find a solution very quickly And read about deploy on Heroku, its' will improve you knowledges;) Happy coding @MichaelHolborn